# How to RDP into Debian Linux (12) guest machine from Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Anyone know how to remote desktop into a non-Windows guest running in Hyper-V (running on Windows Server 2016)?
I managed to get this to work before, with Kali (without installing anything on Kali - really) and had an RDP that is successful.
Here is a bit of the RDP file (in NotePad++)

```
full address:s:192.168.33.252
pcb:s:7f76eb97-5c4a-404e-ba6e-4b8ae310b140
server port:i:2179
```

Problem is, I want to connect to a Debian 12 instance, but not sure how to change the port number that Hyper-V is listening to. I've looked everywhere, but don't see a place to change the port. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the Guest NIC is a Hyper-V External Switch

Comment: I did that, but it only works for the first guest OS I installed (Kali) - which works fine. It looks like you can only do a single guest RDP at a time, but I refuse to believe HyperV would be that limited.

Comment: FWIW - I spun up an Ubuntu 22 machine in Hyper-V.  I installed, enabled and started XRDP.   From my other machine I have RDP'd into both Kali and Ubuntu at the same time.Both are running from the same other machine here.

Comment: Ok, I didn't use XRDP (no config was done on the Kali box, but you don't actually need it to work - I RDPed via the external switch). So, for the other Linux VMs, I'll install XRDP and be done.  I was hoping there was a way to do this solely with the external switch.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The secret to RDPing into hyperV guest machines is the machine ID and a small change in the RDP file (you have to manually edit the files).

Say you have 3 VMs running in HyperV, but you don't want to install a remote desktop software to each VM (or you can't, for whatever reason, say one is Windows 7 home edition). The way around all of this is already provided by Microsoft's HyperV Manager, in the form of port 2179.

First, you need to get all the VM machine IDs (that you want to RDP into) by launching PowerShell and typing in the following:

```
get-vm | select name, ID
```

This will return a list of all the machines with their IDs. looks like:

```
Name            Id
----            --
Kali2           8a519798-70c0-41f2-8158-f56f0f83fb92
Kali3           7f76eb97-5c4a-404e-ba6e-4b8ae310b140
Debian1         c94dfe04-5d6b-4a48-9653-2a92ce492720
```

Next, you simply need to create a new RDP file, then edit it with notepad (or any text editor), and change the following 3 items:

```
full address:s:192.168.33.252
pcb:s:8a519798-70c0-41f2-8158-f56f0f83fb92
server port:i:2179
```

Where you see full address, type in the address of the Host machine (server), NOT the ip address of the guest machine. The full address will be the same for all your RDP files.

On the second line where it shows **pcb:s:** put in the machine ID for that specific machine.

On the third line, server port, put in 2179 . This will be the same for all your RDP files.

The only thing that will change will be the ID (the IP and Port will not change). Save each RDP file separately.

In my example here, the second machine's first 3 RDP file lines will look like so:

```
full address:s:192.168.33.252
pcb:s:7f76eb97-5c4a-404e-ba6e-4b8ae310b140
server port:i:2179
```

And the third machine's first 3 lines like so:

```
full address:s:192.168.33.252
pcb:s:c94dfe04-5d6b-4a48-9653-2a92ce492720
server port:i:2179
```

So, in this example, I have 3 RDP files:

```
Kali2.rdp
Kali3.rdp
Debian1.rdp
```

The only catch with this method is that you cannot copy & paste or do file transfers via these HyperV remote desktop sessions.

Make sure to put your remote desktop user account into the Hyper-V Administrators group! Important!

Comment: That strikes me as taking longer to do it the hard way. XRDP is so very simple to do.

Comment: Really depends on what is considered hard. Installing xrdp on every VM would certainly take longer to do, not to mention manage security settings for each one (requiring login to each). For something like Kali (or any system where you want to be a bit quiet on the network, for say scanning tools), you definitely do not want xrdp installed. Plus you can get access long before the GUI is loaded and see the boot process. You can't do that with xrdp.  Classrooms are another area where this technique would be much faster to implement on fresh OS images - you have remote access immediately.